# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Tags: android, build, android-multidex

I am not able to build release APK. Every time I get DexMergerException.
Here are my build.gradles:

I am using MVVM structure. I have core(package name for core is same as my app package) has my lib where I only write view models, models and network layers.

**Errors I am getting:**

***Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:***

---

***Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete***

---

***Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException***

---

**Program type already present:**

---

**app build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(DEBUG_STORE_FILE)
        }

        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }

    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.puma.one8crew"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue 'string', 'facebook_app_id', FACEBOOK_APP_ID_DEV
        resValue 'string', 'fb_login_protocol_scheme', FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_SCHEME
        manifestPlaceholders += [
                FACEBOOK_APP_ID_BGY: FACEBOOK_APP_ID_DEV,
                FB_LOGIN_SCHEME    : FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_SCHEME
        ]
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    /* productFlavors {

        prod {
            resValue 'string', 'facebook_app_id', FACEBOOK_APP_ID_DEV
            resValue 'string', 'fb_login_protocol_scheme', FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_SCHEME

        }

        stage {
            resValue 'string', 'facebook_app_id', FACEBOOK_APP_ID_DEV
            resValue 'string', 'fb_login_protocol_scheme', FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_SCHEME
        }

    }*/

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "one8crew"
            outputFileName = "${project}_${variant.buildType.name}_${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = true //delete the already predexed libraries
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //Dependencies for LifeCycle Android ViewModel
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation project(':com.wowza.gocoder.sdk')
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'

    //support design lib dependency fot tab
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Below is my core build.gradle and I have also updated the same version for all lib.

**core build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compileOnly 'com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android:com.wowza.gocoder.sdk:1.0b7@aar'
//    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    api('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    api 'swarajsaaj:otpreader:1.1'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    //Dependencies for LifeCycle Android ViewModel
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
//    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    compileOnly project(':com.wowza.gocoder.sdk')
    compile project(':libraries:horizontalcalendar')
    compile project(':libraries:calendarview')

    //Library for setting fonts
    api 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

I tried so many time and I am not able to understand the reason behind this issue.

Comment: Have you try gradle clean and then rebuild projet?

Comment: @SamuelEminet I tried ./gradlew clean..

Comment: No the issue is same

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened today to me and this is what solved the issue:

Find all the dependencies of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.

They all have now different versions. Just place the mouse over them and correct the version numbers (i.e. for me was upgrading maps from 15.0.0 to 15.0.2 and tag-manager to 15.0.1)